# What is the recommended approach on reading application configuration details using netstandard2.0

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

In .NET Framework we have app.config file that gets created when a project is created.But in .NET Core there is no application configuration file when a consoleapp is created.What is the recommended config file for .NET Core applications.

And if netstandard library is referenced to the .NET Core/.NET Framework application if the netstandard library has read the configuration details from the config file,then what classes have to be used. And i think .NET Core supports multiple config files

Comment: They tried hard to keep System.Configuration from infecting .NETCore and .NETStandard.  [But had to give up](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/).

Comment: @HansPassant  Thank you.But the problem is while shipping the netstandard library along with the product will pre-req downloading this nuget package and this nuget package doesn't come along with the sdk

Comment: No idea what that means, it is entirely normal to have a dependency on Nuget packages in a library or .NET project.  Not a problem.

Comment: Won't the product include the bits to the referenced nuget package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET Core, configuration settings can come from different sources:

- File formats (INI, JSON, and XML).
- Command-line arguments.
- Environment variables.
- In-memory .NET objects.
- The unencrypted Secret Manager storage.
- An encrypted user store, such as Azure Key Vault.
- Custom providers (installed or created).

As you see you have numerous options and you can even use multiple of them simultaneously. Choose whatever source you like or the one(s) fitting your scenario the best.

In ASP.NET Core applications JSON files are used usually. (However, settings from command line and environment variables is picked up by default, as well). The naming convention of the JSON config file is *appsettings.json* (but you can use another name if you want). So we can say, *appsettings.json* is roughly the equivalent for *App.config* in .NET Core.

The code sample below shows how you can read settings from a JSON file:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

var configuration = builder.Build();
```

(To compile this, you'll need to have the *Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json* NuGet package installed.)

Thereafter you can access the configuration data by the dictionary-like interface of the *configuration* object.

However, there are more convenient ways to consume the configuration data. The recommended method, which is used in ASP.NET Core extensively, is the Options API.

You find all the details in [the MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=basicconfiguration).

Comment: Thank you.But the problem is while shipping the netstandard library along with the product will pre-req downloading this nuget package and this nuget package doesn't come along with the sdk

Comment: @subbaraoc I've read your question again and I think I answered what you asked. Btw, what do you mean by "shipping the netstandard library"? Netstandard is rather an interface, a set of APIs, which are available on all the platforms which implements it. So you can't ship Netstandard but can ship .NET Core, classic .NET Framework, Mono, etc. runtime (or SDK?)

Comment: When I say netstandard library I meant I build my code targered to netstandard so that the library can be used to access my API,'s in a .netframework or .netcore applications.

Comment: @subbaraoc Ok, got it. Libraries usually don't read configuration settings directly, they provide some interface (e.g. option classes) to get the relevant settings from the end user of the library. It should be up to the end user where and how exactly it stores those settings. I suggest you to study how this is implemented in the framework libraries. (See for example [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCacheServiceCollectionExtensions.cs))